# Cumulative distribution function (CDF) strictly less than

Tags: probability, limits, probability-distributions

Suppose a distribution function for the random variable $X$ is given by 
$$F(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{11} \hfill 0 \hfill & x \lt 0\\ \hfill \dfrac{x}{2} \hfill & 0 \leq x \lt 1\\ \hfill \dfrac{2}{3} \hfill & 1 \leq x \lt 2 \\ \hfill \dfrac{11}{12} \hfill & 2 \leq x \lt 3 \\
\hfill 1 \hfill & 3 \leq x \end{array} \right\}$$

Now suppose we want to find the probability that $X$ is strictly less than $3$. The textbook gives 
$$P\left\{ X \lt 3 \right\} = \lim_{n \to \infty} P\left\{ X \leq 3 - \frac{1}{n} \right\} = \lim_{n \to \infty} F\left( 3 - \frac{1}{n} \right) = \frac{11}{12}$$

The part I am having issues understanding is that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} F\left( 3 - \frac{1}{n} \right) = F\left( \lim_{n \to \infty} 3 - \frac{1}{n} \right) = F(3) = 1 \ne \frac{11}{12} $$

What am I missing here?

Comment: That a CDF is not always continuous from the left hence $\lim F(3-1/n)$ and $F(\lim 3-1/n)$ do not always coincide (and here they do not). In full generality, $\lim F(x-1/n)=P(X<x)$ while $F(x)=\lim F(x+1/n)=P(X\leqslant x)$.

Comment: If its true that for a CDF that $\lim_{b \to \infty} F(b) = 1$ why is not guaranteed that $F(b)$ is left continuous @Did?

Comment: Sorry but your comment is unclear to me.

Comment: @Cameron Such a guarantee would exclude the CDF of discretely distributed random variables; or any random variable with a probability mass component (such as this one).

Comment: @Did I believe its an error or at least ambiguous notation in my textbook. It states that one of the properties of a CDF $F(b)$ is that $\lim_{b \to \infty} F(b) = 1$, however looking on Wikipedia a CDF is defined $lim_{b \to +\infty} F(b) = 1 $ which would be consistent with definitions of a CDF discussed here.

Comment: @CameronP Where is the error? Yes, every CDF $F$ has limit $1$ at $+\infty$ (and $0$ at $-\infty$). This is unrelated to left- and right-continuity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposing $F$ is left continuous. That is your error. The only continuity condition for a PDF is right continuity.